# How to get all running activities android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I was wondering is there a way of getting a list with all running activities ?

Comment: i think you ment to ask these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304685/how-to-get-the-list-of-running-applications please search

Comment: No, there is no way. See:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/57f051efdcfc0c17#

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand there will only one activity running at a time that will be your active activity on screen, other activities will be in paused or Stopped state if any.

Comment: That's correct Tushar. Reference: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: In most cases other activities will be in stopped state.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know there is no built in way to get a list of running activities (assuming running - means non-destroyed activities).

If you only need a list of activities in your application, you can create some kind of "registrar" mechanism, so each activity registers in `onCreate()` and unregisters in `onDestroy()`. This should be some singleton class, because it should automatically be "cleared" if application is killed (as opposed to storing list of active activities in DB).