# How to know whether another app is executing or is closed from my app code in Android

Tags: android

In my app I want to know that when another app that is installed on the phone is executing and when it's not. Can you introduce me a function or and class to make the trick?
Thank for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the list of running applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304685/how-to-get-the-list-of-running-applications)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isInstalled(Context context, String packageName)
{
    PakageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
          pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
          return true;
     } catch (PackageNotFoundException ex) {
           return false;
     }

}

public boolean isRunning(Context context, String packageName)
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.Activity_SERVICE);
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo info : am.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
      for (String runPack : info.pkgList) {
         if (runPack.equals(packageName)) return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You need a permission "android.permission.GET_TASKS" to access ActivityManager.

Comment: Starting with Android 5.1.1, this method will only return the processes of your app so this method won't work.

Comment: I want this can work when my app is close and that app is execute. the above answer can work for this ?