# How can i verify if certain app is running on Android?

Tags: android

i trying to make an android app, that verify if certain app is running, if the certain app is not running my app have to open it, but i don´t know how to do for to verify if the certain app is running? can somebody help me please...

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-on-android

See the accepted answer.

Comment: or here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22503513/1771254

Answer (score 0):

you can use TaskManager see this Sample Code 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2955965&stc=1&d=1412353638

```
    final   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

/**recentTasks.get(0) Activity that is on top >> your app and number 1 will next **/
    String pack = recentTasks.get(0).baseActivity.toShortString();
```

also you can get info of running app with UsageStats like this

```
try{
  AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(APP_OPS_SERVICE);
  int mode = appOps.checkOp("android:get_usage_stats", android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
  if(mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {//should turn on UsageStats
    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = mUsageStatsManager
                    .queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,
            System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000*60,           //begin
            System.currentTimeMillis());                    //end
    Collections.sort(queryUsageStats, new LastTimeLaunchedComparator());
    try{
      CustomUsageStats customUsageStats = new CustomUsageStats();
      customUsageStats.usageStats = queryUsageStats.get(1);
      String previousAppPack = customUsageStats.usageStats.getPackageName();
      //the package of app before your app
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

Comment: This approach was deprecated years ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare i added another solution.