# How to get the last app running in foreground

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm creating a launcher for Android and I want to get the last running app in foreground i.e. the last app that was closed or minimized. I want to do this in the onResume() method of my launcher activity.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304685/how-to-get-the-list-of-running-applications

Comment: you can't get that info