# Receive other applications' usage time data

Tags: android

I'm working on an android project. I need to receive other applications' usage time. I simply just need how many application is running and what are they. How can I access these kinds of data?

I found some articles about receiving another's SQLite DB but I really don't need this.

Comment: Have you checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304685/how-to-get-the-list-of-running-applications

Comment: Yes but this code only shows my running app information, i need names of running applications on device currently.

Comment: Okay, please  check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You may follow the steps:**

- Retrieve the list of the tasks that are currently running by calling 
  [getRunningTasks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int))
- Go through each of the    task and retrieve the `PackageName`
- Get `AppName` from the `PackagName`
- Add the `AppName` in a list

**Here is the implementation:**

```
private List<String> getRunningAppList()
{
    Set<String> appNameList = new HashSet<>();

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ActivityManager aManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Get the list of the tasks that are currently running
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> infoList = aManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo taskInfo : infoList)
    {
        // Get the packageNAme
        String pkgName = taskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
        String appName = null;
        // Get the appName
        try
        {
            appName = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(pkgName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Adding the appName
        appNameList.add(appName);
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(appNameList);
}
```

Comment: Sabbir, i don't know why you did not respect my opinion. getRunningTasks is deprecated mate. I already checked your comment but it is not useful.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. Your comment "Yes but this code only shows my running app information, i need names of running applications on device currently." did not mean that. I know that getRunningTasks() is deprecated but it will work, I think. However, you may use getRunningAppProcesses() method instead of getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE).

Comment: As i said both getRunningTasks() and getRunningAppProcesses() are same. They show only my application's name. Just respect my solution bro.

Answer (score 1):

Using `UsageStats`, `UsageStatsManager` is simply the best approach for this topic.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats

`UsageStats.getLastTimeUsed()` informs you about a specific application's last usage time by date format.