# Retrieving the name of the active application in the foreground

Tags: android, android-service

Is there a possibility to know the name of the application that is running at the moment and that my application that works in the background can it get it.

"I need to get name of working applications in real time"

Comment: Yes. You should combine AccessibilityServices and UsageStatsManager.

Comment: @EliasFazel Accessibility services for that reason won't be allowed on Google Play

Comment: I know but the question is about possibility ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the list of running applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304685/how-to-get-the-list-of-running-applications)