# Can we find apps that are running along in android with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Basically get the list of all the recent apps and change some of their entities like volume of a specific app.

Comment: Typically, source codes of apps are not public.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to call some Java code (which is possible, see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

And for the info on how to get a list of running apps in Android, here's a good start:
[How to get the list of running applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304685/how-to-get-the-list-of-running-applications)