# How can I get the name of the app running on the device with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to get the name of running application and want to perform some action according to the input.

Like if current app is music player, turn volume to max.

Comment: i don't think you can do that as of android os will prevent you from doing that

Comment: Look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name/29513147 and this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304685/how-to-get-the-list-of-running-applications